# Firefox Clear Search Terms When Tab Closed

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I am using Firefox (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.15) Gecko/2009101601 Firefox/3.0.15 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)). I want to be able to clear the search terms in the search box when I close a tab. I am using Google as my search provider.

Is this possible with Firefox `about:config` or do I have to write a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't clear the search box when you close a tab, but the [Clear Search add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14534) will clear it instantly after you make your search.

Comment: does not work anymore with firefox 35